# Displaying build duration in email notification

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Currently i am using declarative pipeline. In my email notification i want to pass build duration as well. Any idea how to post build duration in emailtext .

Answer (score 0):

Use the durationString of the currentBuild:

```
    def elapsed = currentBuild.durationString.replace(" and counting","")
```

It will give you the time elapsed until the calculation sentence, so you better activate it just before sending the email.